# RHEL leapp upgrade fails on reboot

Tags: rhel7, rhel8

I am trying to upgrade several physical servers from RHEL 7.9 to RHEL 8.6 offline. So far the process was successful on 1 server. On the server that I have the issue everything works fine and when I reboot the server it goes to emergency mode. Rebooting from emergency mode I can go back to the server's current operating system (RHEL 7.9).
Running:
`leapp preupgrade --no-rhsm --enablerepo local1 --enablerepo local2`
comes back with no errors.
After that I am running:
`leapp upgrade --no-rhsm --enablerepo local1 --enablerepo local2`
and it completes without any issues. I do the reboot and after choosing "Upgrade RHEL 8 initramfs" is trying to do the upgrade and it fails.
Here is the last part of the leapp-upgrade.log

```
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target System Upgrade.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost systemd[1]: Starting System Upgrade...
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1543]: starting upgrade hook
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1543]: /bin/upgrade: line 19: /sysroot/var/tmp/system-upgrade.state: No such file or directory
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   WARNING: locking_type (4) is deprecated, using --sysinit --readonly.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   Allowing activation with --readonly --sysinit.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   WARNING: Couldn't find device with uuid qGbnBb-LLqH-seg7-NEX3-NPTD-veJk-KLA3SK.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   WARNING: VG rhel is missing PV qGbnBb-LLqH-seg7-NEX3-NPTD-veJk-KLA3SK (last written to /dev/sdi1).
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   Refusing activation of partial LV rhel/root.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   Refusing activation of partial LV rhel/data.  Use '--activationmode partial' to override.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   0 logical volume(s) in volume group "rhel" now active
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   Allowing activation with --readonly --sysinit.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1546]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg01" now active
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1567]: Spawning container sysroot on /sysroot.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1567]: Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (md0): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (md0): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: XFS (dm-1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: XFS (dm-1): Ending clean mount
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1570]: mount: special device /dev/mapper/rhel-data does not exist
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     CiscoVD  Hypervisor            PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] 124727295 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 17 00 00 00
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel:  sdi: sdi1
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI removable disk
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ==> Processing phase `InitRamStart`
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ====> * remove_upgrade_boot_entry
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]:         Remove boot entry for Leapp provided initramfs.
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]: Process Process-192:
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     self.run()
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/leapp/repository/actor_definition.py", line 72, in _do_run
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     actor_instance.run(*args, **kwargs)
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/leapp/actors/__init__.py", line 290, in run
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     self.process(*args)
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/share/leapp-repository/repositories/system_upgrade/common/actors/removeupgradebootentry/actor.py", line 20, in process
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     remove_boot_entry()
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/share/leapp-repository/repositories/system_upgrade/common/actors/removeupgradebootentry/libraries/removeupgradebootentry.py", line 41, in remove_boot_entry
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     '/bin/mount', '-a'
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/leapp/libraries/stdlib/__init__.py", line 188, in run
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]:     result=result
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]: CalledProcessError: Command ['/bin/mount', '-a'] failed with exit code 32.
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ==========================================================================================================
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: Actor remove_upgrade_boot_entry unexpectedly terminated with exit code: 1 - Please check the above details
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ==========================================================================================================
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: Debug output written to /var/log/leapp/leapp-upgrade.log
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ============================================================
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]:                            REPORT
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ============================================================
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ============================================================
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]:                        END OF REPORT
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: ============================================================
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1585]: Answerfile has been generated at /var/log/leapp/answerfile
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost kernel: XFS (dm-1): Unmounting Filesystem
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[1567]: Container sysroot failed with error code 1.
```

All the physical drives are reporting ok, all the volume groups are reporting ok and all logical volumes are reporting ok after going to a normal boot.
Even the missing PV qGbnBb-..... is mounted after a normal boot.
Could please help me overcome the above issue as it is very critical for my client?
If you need any further log files or output of any command I will be happy to provide it.

[Amendment]
The result of `pvs -o +uuid`

```
  /dev/md1   vg01 lvm2 a--  <438.52g <348.52g o2821Q-5Re1-UiCZ-V2LJ-f7Qg-hwpX-CqD1ib
  /dev/sdc1  rhel lvm2 a--  <447.13g       0  Iq1PHS-zOk5-2uCw-Ga9A-uo4F-DjkQ-WqpU5S
  /dev/sdd1  rhel lvm2 a--  <447.13g       0  5co7Pi-YiaO-wPyH-Fd3N-rDyC-UPjc-1FJNYx
  /dev/sde1  rhel lvm2 a--  <447.13g       0  46oNJ3-sf3n-5Lqc-6ZZv-dN3U-guzA-5s7ZRa
  /dev/sdf1  rhel lvm2 a--  <447.13g       0  U2iWT4-c7lP-7Zp8-ZNTJ-EtF3-mcyQ-nDgU6A
  /dev/sdg1  rhel lvm2 a--  <447.13g       0  R9vj56-XNvi-xEUu-DXLs-fPU3-MnIC-gtbZXY
  /dev/sdh1  rhel lvm2 a--  <447.13g       0  WCcfjx-Ffzp-OwLz-BHGX-HIpo-qtFC-HuMPVp
  /dev/sdi1  rhel lvm2 a--   <59.47g       0  qGbnBb-LLqH-seg7-NEX3-NPTD-veJk-KLA3SK
```

[Amendment 2]
The results of `vgs -o +devices`

```
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree    Devices
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdi1(2424)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdc1(0)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdd1(0)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sde1(0)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdf1(0)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdg1(0)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdh1(0)
  rhel   7   2   0 wz--n-   <2.68t       0  /dev/sdi1(0)
  vg01   1   2   0 wz--n- <438.52g <348.52g /dev/md1(0)
  vg01   1   2   0 wz--n- <438.52g <348.52g /dev/md1(12800)
```

[Amendment 3]
The results of `lvs --all -o +devices`

```
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sdc1(0)
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sdd1(0)
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sde1(0)
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sdf1(0)
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sdg1(0)
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sdh1(0)
  data rhel -wi-ao---- <2.63t                                                     /dev/sdi1(0)
  root rhel -wi-a----- 50.00g                                                     /dev/sdi1(2424)
  root vg01 -wi-ao---- 50.00g                                                     /dev/md1(0)
  var  vg01 -wi-ao---- 40.00g                                                     /dev/md1(12800)
```

[Amendment 4]
The results of the command `lvscan`

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/rhel/data' [<2.63 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg01/root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg01/var' [40.00 GiB] inherit
```

Answer (score 0):

Some mount points are missing check why.

```
Sep 05 04:15:52 localhost upgrade[1570]: mount: special device /dev/mapper/rhel-data does not exist
```

And

```
Sep 05 04:15:59 localhost upgrade[2048]: CalledProcessError: Command ['/bin/mount', '-a'] failed with exit code 32.
```

Comment: the result from the command ```mount | grep mapper```:   
```/dev/mapper/vg01-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/vg01-var on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/rhel-data on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)```
To me, there are all there

Comment: try `mount -a` in single user mode to validate post upgrade. Also share if pv `qGbnBb-LLqH-seg7-NEX3-NPTD-veJk-KLA3SK.` is actually exists and usable or not. Add these details to your question please.

Comment: I cannot run at this stage the ```mount -a```, as the server is a production server and need to do it after hours. I just posted the results of ```pvs -o +uuid``` which the showcase the "missing" pv is available.

Comment: can you add output of `vgs --options +devices` and `lvs --all --options +devices` to question?

Answer (score 0):

So after a long googling around and testing I discovered the following bug which was happening to me:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1927688
The work-around helped me to over come the issue but it led to a new issue which was a faulty grub 2 configuration. So here is what I did to resolve my issue.
After running the upgrade command `leapp upgrade --no-rhsm --enablerepo local1 --enablerepo local2` I did a reboot as requested to complete the upgrade process.
A) Upon rebooting and entering the grub2 menu I typed `e` while the `RHEL 8 Upgrade Initramfs` was selected.
B) At the end of **CMDLINUX**, I added the `rd.break=upgrade` option. Save and continue.
C) After entering single user boot mode I execute the commands as described in the above link.

```
sed -i 's/locking_type = 4/locking_type = 1/' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
lvm vgchange -ay --config ' global {locking_type=1} '
lvm vgck --updatemetadata rhel
sed -i 's/locking_type = 1/locking_type = 4/' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
exit
```

D) The system boot as expected the initramfs of the upgrade and the upgrade completed successfully.
However on reboot, I got into grub rescue mode. To resolve this, I used a RHEL 8.6 media that I had to perform the off-line upgrade and boot from that media.
E) After booting with the above media, I chose to repair an installed OS, and I follow the prompts to get the right shell access. Doing so it automatically chose where my grub was installed (for my case /dev/md) and from there I repaired my grub by:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
grub2-install /dev/md
reboot
```

And there it was my brand new RHEL 8.6 boot option. I got into the system as per usual.